# How to calculate standard error with differing sample sizes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm relatively new to data analysis in R, so I apologize if I do not use the correct terminology. I've looked around on here, but could not find this specific question.

I am using the dplyr package to calculate the mean, standard deviation, and standard error of a my variables in a data set. However, I had to omit two samples, meaning there is now a different sample size for each of my variables.

Using the count function:

```
nTable \<- count(df, variable)

variables         n
\<fct\>          \<int\>
1 A                13
2 A Control        13
3 B                12
4 B Control        13
5 C                13
6 C Control        13
7 D                13
8 D Control        13
9 E                12
10 E Control       13
11 Standard        13
```

You can see that variable 'B' and 'E' have one less sample than the other variables. How can I code to reflect this using the summarise function? If all sample sizes were the same, this would be straight forward:

```
Summary <- df %>% group_by(variable) %>%  
summarise(Mean=mean(value), SD=sd(value),
SE=sd(value)/sqrt((13)))
```

But is there a way to replace the sample size above (13) with an individual sample size per each variable?

Here is what I tried so far, with no luck:

```
nTable <- count(df, variable)
nTable

n <- nTable$n
n

Summary <- df %>% group_by(variable) %>%  
summarise(Mean=mean(value), SD=sd(value),
SE=sd(value)/sqrt((n)))
```

But I get this message:

```
Warning message:
Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was 
deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember 
that 
`reframe()` always returns an ungrouped data frame and
 adjust accordingly.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this 
warning was generated.
```

I am not quite sure what this message is trying to tell me, or how I can get my desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. Paste the output of `dput(df)` here.

Comment: try `sqrt(n())` ?

Comment: @BenBolker, thank you so much! That worked! Really appreciate your time, you certainly saved me a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

(Promoted from a comment)

This should work if you use `sqrt(n())` instead of `sqrt(n)` (see `?dplyr::n`)